# How to show all errors at once?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to show all erros at once in my project but I don't know how to do this. Please help. Thanks.

```
signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             if ((validateName() || validateLastName() || validateEmail() || validatePassword() || validateRepeatPassword()) != true) {
                                                 String email = uEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                                                 String password = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                                                 fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                         if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                             Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext()), "Authentication failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             openLoginActivity();
                                                         } else {
                                                             Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             openPhoneActivity();
                                                         }

                                                     }
                                                 });
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }

        );
```

Here is an example of validate :

```
private boolean validateRepeatPassword() {
        String repeatPasswordInput = uRepeatPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordInput = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (repeatPasswordInput.isEmpty()) {
            uRepeatPasswordError.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return true;
        } else if (repeatPasswordInput.equals(passwordInput)) {
            uRepeatPasswordError.setError("Repeated password must be equalse to the first ");
            return true;
        } else {
            uRepeatPasswordError.setError(null);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please write your suggests to solve my problem below.

Comment: what do you mean? In the code you 've shown, it is not possible for both errors to happen at the same time

Comment: I know it's impossible to do this in this form. I'm asking someone to edit the code so that it returns all errors at once.

Comment: it can't return "all errors at once", because it is not possible for a text to both be empty, and equal to another non empty String. (there 's an error in your logic there, hope you got it)there's also no point of calling toString() on the result of a getText()

Comment: Yes i got it, so what can I do to compare two editText fields like a password confirm ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are short-circuiting the condition (which I think you should do).
But if you really want to trigger all checking you can

```
signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                         @Override
                                         public void onClick(View v) {
                                             boolean isInvalidName = validateName();
                                             boolean isInvalidLastName = validateLastName();
                                             boolean isInvalidEmail = validateEmail();
                                             boolean isInvalidPassword = validatePassword();
                                             boolean isInvalidRepeatPassword = validateRepeatPassword()
                                             if (!(isInvalidName || isInvalidLastName || isInvalidEmail || isInvalidPassword || isInvalidRepeatPassword)) {
                                                 String email = uEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                                                 String password = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                                                 fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(SignUpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                                         if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                             Toast.makeText((getApplicationContext()), "Authentication failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             openLoginActivity();
                                                         } else {
                                                             Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                             openPhoneActivity();
                                                         }

                                                     }
                                                 });
                                             }
                                         }
                                     }

        );
```

This way you trigger all checkings.

I hope this helps.

An alternative is to return all string errors and concatenate them.

```
private String validateRepeatPassword() {
        String repeatPasswordInput = uRepeatPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordInput = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (repeatPasswordInput.isEmpty()) {
            return "Field can't be empty";
        } else if (repeatPasswordInput.equals(passwordInput)) {
            return "Repeated password must be equals to the first ";
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a text watchers on the EditTexts. Disable the button in case of error after user input. 
the editText.setError(msg) can be build up there accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean validateRepeatPassword() {
        String repeatPasswordInput = uRepeatPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String passwordInput = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        if (repeatPasswordInput.isEmpty()) {
            uRepeatPasswordError.setError("Field can't be empty");
            return true;
        } else if (repeatPasswordInput.equals(passwordInput)) {
            uRepeatPasswordError.setError("Repeated password must be equalse to the first ");
            return true;
        } else {
            uRepeatPasswordError.setError(null);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Let's look at this method, since this is where you have issues.

Firstly, your 'getText()' is a bit weird.

```
String repeatPasswordInput = uRepeatPassword.getText().toString().trim();
String passwordInput = uPassword.getText().toString().trim();
```

getText() likely already returns a String. There's little reason to call toString() on it.

```
String repeatPasswordInput = uRepeatPassword.getText().trim();
String passwordInput = uPassword.getText().trim();
```

should do.

Secondly, your business logic is off on your second validation.

```
if (repeatPasswordInput.equals(passwordInput)) {
    uRepeatPasswordError.setError("Repeated password must be equalse to the first ");
    return true;
}
```

Your error method says that the inputs must be identical, but you only give that error when they are, actually, identical. Most likely, you meant this:

```
if (!repeatPasswordInput.equals(passwordInput)) {
    uRepeatPasswordError.setError("Repeated password must be equalse to the first ");
    return true;
}
```

Now, to show all the errors. What you are doing is a bit this:

```
private boolean isValid() {
  if ( aIsInvalid()) {
    errorField.setText("A is invalid");
    return true;
  } else if ( bIsInvalid() ) {
    errorField.setText("B is invalid");
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If I understand your question correct, both a and b can be invalid, and if so, you want to show both the messages.
First: remove the return true statements. The moment you hit one of those, your validation ends. So, do something like this:

```
private boolean isValid() {
  boolean returnVal = false;
  if ( aIsInvalid()) {
    errorField.setText("A is invalid");
    returnVal = true;
  } else if ( bIsInvalid() ) {
    errorField.setText("B is invalid");
    returnVal = true;
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

Now, the entire block will run, because you only return a value on the last line. It won't work as you want it (yet), though, since your else statement makes sure that if a is invalid, you don't test for b. Change the code to this:

```
private boolean isValid() {
  boolean returnVal = false;
  if ( aIsInvalid()) {
    errorField.setText("A is invalid");
    returnVal = true;
  } 
  if ( bIsInvalid() ) {
    errorField.setText("B is invalid");
    returnVal = true;
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

Now, it will test them both. Still not good, though, since if both are invalid, your second errormessage will overwrite your first one.

So:

```
private boolean isValid() {
  boolean returnVal = false;
  String msg = "";
  if ( aIsInvalid()) {
    returnVal = true;
    msg = "A is invalid";
  }
  if ( bIsInvalid() ) {
    if ( returnVal ) a += "/n";
    msg += "B is invalid";
    returnVal = true;
  }
  if ( returnVal ) {
    errorField.setText(msg);
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

This way, if your field is big enough, it will show both messages. Edits must be at least 6 characters;